# ButtonType "PAYMENT" and "no_shipping", "no_note"

Tags: php, paypal

I noticed that if I create a "BUYNOW" button, I can set some variable (in ButtonVar) called "no_shipping" or "no_note" and I won't find any input about the shipping address or notes for the facilitator.
When I change the type of the button to "PAYMENT", theese variable became useless and I'll find the inputs.
What can I do? Thanks.

```
$buttonVar = array( "return=xxx",
                    "cancel_return=xxx",
                    "notify_url=xxx",
                    "business=xxx");
    $buttonVar[] = "item_name=xxx";
    $buttonVar[] = "custom=".$Token;
    $buttonVar[] = "invoice=".mysql_insert_id();
    $buttonVar[] = "tax_rate=3.5";
    $buttonVar[] = "currency_code=EUR";
    $buttonVar[] = "no_note=1";
    $buttonVar[] = "no_shipping=1";
    $buttonVar[] = "image_url=xxx";
    $buttonVar[] = "amount=" . number_format($Totale,2);
    $buttonVar[] = "subtotal=" . number_format($Totale,2);
$createButtonRequest = new BMCreateButtonRequestType();
/*
 *  (Optional) The kind of button code to create. It is one of the following values:
    HOSTED - A secure button stored on PayPal; default for all buttons except View Cart, Unsubscribe, and Pay Now
    ENCRYPTED - An encrypted button, not stored on PayPal; default for View Cart button
    CLEARTEXT - An unencrypted button, not stored on PayPal; default for Unsubscribe button
    TOKEN - A secure button, not stored on PayPal, used only to initiate the Hosted Solution checkout flow; default for Pay Now button. Since version 65.1

 */
$createButtonRequest->ButtonCode = TOKEN;
$createButtonRequest->ButtonType = PAYMENT;
$createButtonRequest->ButtonVar = $buttonVar;
$createButtonReq = new BMCreateButtonReq();
$createButtonReq->BMCreateButtonRequest = $createButtonRequest;
$paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(Configuration::getAcctAndConfig());
try {
    $createButtonResponse = $paypalService->BMCreateButton($createButtonReq);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    //require 'PayPal/Error.php';
    exit;
}
if(isset($createButtonResponse)) {
    /*echo "<table>";
    //echo "<tr><td>Ack :</td><td><div id='Ack'>$createButtonResponse->Ack</div> </td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>HostedButtonID :</td><td><div id='HostedButtonID'>". $createButtonResponse->HostedButtonID ."</div> </td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Email :</td><td><div id='Email'>". $createButtonResponse->Email ."</div> </td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
            */
    echo "<a target=\"_blank\" class=\"mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent\" href=\"".$createButtonResponse->Email."\">Paga con PayPal</a>";
    //echo $createButtonResponse->Website;
    //echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: It is always recommendable to share your source code.

Comment: @Blackbam done.